# create new shapes out of intersecting paths in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I've used the pen tool to create a number of intersecting, irregular paths. I want to use the irregular shapes created by the intersection--to fill the space, for example, or to change the lines to another color between the intersecting points. I've looked for solutions such as trying to add anchor points at the intersections, but I haven't found anything that works.

[image]

Comment: Select all your lines and click once inside with the Shapebuilder Tool (Shift+M).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new shapes from intersecting paths in Adobe Illustrator, you can use the Shape Builder Tool. Here’s a quick guide:

1. **Select the intersecting paths** you want to merge into a new shape.
2. Choose the **Shape Builder Tool** from the toolbar or press **Shift+**M.
3. **Drag across the intersecting paths** to merge them into a new shape.

For more detailed operations like cutting paths or dividing them, the **Pathfinder** panel can be very useful. You can use options like **Divide** to create anchor points at intersections and then delete or modify sections as needed.

Answer (score 0):

object, expand fill and stroke. then select all go to pathfinder -» divide. Then i guess you ll want to ungroup.

Try different things on pathfinder. You could find it amusing.

Also, i would double the whole thing and do the steps i wanted, but you ll learn while you play with it.